# Objective C: How to review code in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am new user in stack overflow & i am also a iOS Developer. I want to know how to review our code?

What is the naming convention through coding? What is the guidelines for Variable name, class name. How can we manage this?

Comment: It will follow the same conventions as with 99% of coding languages. I'm not quite sure what you mean by *How can we manage this?*

Comment: The basic naming convention is the same as C/C++/Java:  Leading upper case for class names, leading lower case for variable names, all upper case for #define names.  Naming conventions for constants and enums are not as well settled.

Comment: @jbutler483 - Microsoft (of course) uses their own conventions for C-style languages, and non-C-style languages tend to be different too, so it's not the same "as with all coding languages".

Comment: For naming conventions, see [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has laid out a set of guidelines as to how code should be written for maximum clarity and integration with the frameworks. In addition, there are some undocumented conventions that Cocoa developers often use.

**Class Names:**

1. Class names are always capitalized.
2. **Objective-C** doesn't have namespaces, so prefix your class names with initials. This avoids "*namespace collision*," which is a situation where two pieces of code have the same name but do different things. Classes created by **Cocoa Dev Central** would probably be prefixed with "**CDC**".
3. If you subclass a standard Cocoa class, it's good idea to combine your prefix with the superclass name, such as **CDCTableView**.

**Variable Names:**

1. Variable names start with lower-case letters, but are internally capitalized wherever a new word appears:

   ```
    NSString * streetAddress  = @"1 Infinite Loop";
    NSString * cityName       = @"Cupertino";
    NSString * countyName     = @"Santa Clara";
   ```

--------- **Correct Way** ---------

```
     NSString       * hostName;
     NSNumber       * ipAddress;
     NSArray        * accounts;
```

--------- **Incorrect Way** ---------

```
     NSString       * HST_NM;      // all caps and too terse
     NSNumber       * theip;       // a word or abbreviation?
     NSMutableArray * nsma;        // completely ambiguous
```

2. Variables can't start with a number, no spaces, no special characters other than underscores.
3. Apple discourages using an underscore as a prefix for a private instance variable.

   ```
    NSString * name    // correct!
    NSString * _name   // _incorrect_
   ```

**Variable Names: Indicating Type**

1. In terms of real-world practice, a variable name usually does not indicate the type if it is something common like NSString, NSArray, NSNumber or BOOL.

**Correct**

```
     NSString       * accountName;
     NSMutableArray * mailboxes;
     NSArray        * defaultHeaders;
     BOOL             userInputWasUpdated;
```

**OK, But Not Ideal**

```
     NSString       * accountNameString;
     NSMutableArray * mailboxArray;
     NSArray        * defaultHeadersArray;
     BOOL             userInputWasUpdatedBOOL;
```

2. If a variable is not one of these types, the name should reflect it. Also, there are certain classes that you only need one instance of. In this case, just name the variable based on the class name. Font manager is a good example of this.

**When to Indicate Type**

```
     NSImage             * previewPaneImage;  // self-explanatory
     NSProgressIndicator * uploadIndicator;   // shows progress for uploads
     NSFontManager       * fontManager;       // only one of these, basic name ok
```

**Method Names**

1. Methods are perhaps the most important topic we can talk about. Most object-oriented languages use a syntax.
2. While these methods names are easy to write the first time, the actual behavior is not clear. This is much more of a problem amidst massive amounts of surrounding code.
3. Cocoa programmers think from the end, choosing a method name based on how it will look in actual use. Let's say I want to write an in-memory file object written to disk.

In Cocoa/Objective-C, it looks like this:

```
    [fileWrapper writeToFile: path atomically: YES updateFilenames: YES];
```

**Method Names: Accessors**

1. In constrast to many other languages, Objective-C discourages use of the "get" prefix on simple accessors. Instance variables and methods can have the same name, so use this to your advantage:

**Correct!**

```
      - (NSString *) name;
      - (NSString *) color;

      name  = [object name];
      color = [object color];
```

**Incorrect**

```
      - (NSString *) getName;
      - (NSColor  *) getColor;

      name  = [object getName];
      color = [object getColor];
```

2. The "get" prefix is, however, used in situations when you're returning a value indirectly via a memory address:

*When to Use "Get" Prefix*

// copy objects from the NSArray to the buffer

```
      id *buffer = (id *) malloc(sizeof(id) * [array count]);
      [array getObjects: buffer];
      ( Don't worry if you don't know what malloc does. )
      The "set" prefix is always used on setters, though:


      [object setName:  name];
      [object setColor: color];
```

**Adjectives**

1. Not all accessors return values like name, date, height, etc. Some represent a particularly quality of an object. These are often represented by **BOOLs**.
2. For example, "selectable". In Objective-C, the getter for this key is called -isSelectable, but the setter is -setSelectable:

   ```
       BOOL selectable = [textView isSelectable];
       BOOL editable   = [textView isEditable];

       [textView setSelectable: YES];    // no "is"
       [textView setEditable:   YES];    // no "is"

        // if textview is editable.

       if ([textView isEditable])
       [textView setEditable: NO];
   ```
3. Keep in mind that naming your accessors according to all of these rules isn't purely an issue of clarity and aesthetics. Cocoa relies heavily on **KVC** for much of its magic, and KVC relies on properly-named accessors.

I think this will help you.

Comment: Not that I disagree but from the beginning you use Apple Discourage. So have you got any Documentation to back these statements up with? By the way I do agree with a lot of stuff in your answer just think it could be made better with documentation as well.

Comment: I accept this answer, i think this is some of clear answer about this :)

Comment: "Apple discourages using an underscore as a prefix for a private instance variable". Not true. When using an instance variable that backs a property, that's precisely when you should use underscore.

Comment: There is one thing I have noticed you have missed when it comes to class categories. A class category file naming convention should be something like `CDCTableView+CategoryName.h` with the CategoryName being that of your category that you have created. Also agree with `Rob` this was the reason behind asking for documentation.

Comment: Re prefix for ivars, the underscore _is_ recommended for ivars backing properties. According to [Declared Properties and Instance Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE) of _Coding Guidelines for Cocoa_: "Usually, you should not access instance variables directly; instead you should use accessor methods (you do access instance variables directly in init and dealloc methods). To help to signal this, prefix instance variable names with an underscore (_)..."

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for that. But if i declare a variable with property synthesize & i forget to synthesize that variable. that time apple automatic give a warning and tells for (_)

Comment: Yes, if you don't `@synthesize` explicitly, the compiler will, by default, synthesize an ivar with the leading underscore and will warn you if you accidentally added your own ivar without the underscore. That warning goes away if you add the underscore. This behavior (as well as the documentation references I provided earlier) demonstrates that it is incorrect to claim that "Apple discourages using an underscore as a prefix for a private instance variable." Quite to the contrary, they advise that there are times in which you should do precisely that (and will do so by default).

Answer (score 0):

Check the apple document

Just give some example URLS

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.pdf

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html

https://github.com/catshive/iOSCodingGuidelines

Comment: I Already took a look on this site. I need clean clarification about this